# ActiveRecord: advanced querying with includes() or joins()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, querying

I'm trying to implement some kind of "smart" search using ActiveRecord. 
For example, I have two models: User and Practice.
I want to find all practices with active only users.

I'm trying to achieve that in these ways:

```
Practice.joins(:users)
.where('LOWER(name) LIKE :search OR (LOWER(users.first_name) LIKE :search OR LOWER(users.last_name) LIKE :search)', search: "%#{params[:search].downcase}%")
.where(users: {removed_at: nil}).distinct.limit(10)
```

This gives me practices with all users(both active and removed)

If I try another option (using includes() instead of joins()):

```
Practice.includes(:users).where('LOWER(name) LIKE :search OR (LOWER(users.first_name) LIKE :search OR LOWER(users.last_name) LIKE :search)', search: "%#{params[:search].downcase}%")
                 .where(users: {removed_at: nil}).distinct.limit(10)
```

I get right object structure when practice name is entered as a search query, but if I use user's name as a search param - I only can see this particular user inside the practice, and I want to be able to have all active users in found practice in that case.

Could you please help me to figure out how to achieve that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add conditional association:

```
has_many :active_users, -> {where(active: true)}, class_name: "User"
```

And then use both `includes` and `references`

```
Practice.includes(:active_users).references(:users)...
```

This works in Rails 4.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need sometimes to fetch all users, both active and inactive, so I can't add conditional association.

Comment: You can use both, any number of them. Just replace active_users with users

Comment: Indeed, but this doesn't work as expected. This code also gives me all users instead of active only.